# Drawable ou Mipmap?? Qual a diferença?

Tags: android, android-studio

A partir versão 1.1 do android studio surgio uma nova pasta chamada mipmap com os mesmos recursos da drawable. Qual a utilidade dessa nova pasta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pasta mipmap é exclusivamente para colocar ícones que serão utilizados na aplicação.

Segue uma explicação da Google sobre esse caso:

> It’s best practice to place your app icons in mipmap- folders (not the
>   drawable- folders) because they are used at resolutions different from
>   the device’s current density. For example, an xxxhdpi app icon can be
>   used on the launcher for an xxhdpi device.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Foram alteradas para mipmaps, deixando a nomenclatura drawable apenas para arquivos de PNG, JPEG, GIF ou arquivos de imagem, 9-Patch, e arquivos XML que descrevem formas Drawable ou objetos Drawable que contêm vários estados (normal, pressionados, ou focalizado).

Resumidamente os mipmaps são utilizados para ícones lançador de aplicativos. O sistema Android retém os recursos nesta pasta (e pastas específicos de densidade, como mipmap-xxxhdpi), independentemente da resolução da tela do dispositivo onde o aplicativo está instalado. Esse comportamento permite que os aplicativos escolham o melhor ícone/resolução para seu aplicativo para exibir na tela inicial. Para obter mais informações sobre como usar as pastas mipmap, consulte Gerenciando Lançador ícones como recursos mipmap.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html