# Quando eu devo usar mipmaps?

Tags: android, drawable, android-resources

Depois que o Google começou a adicionar *Mipmaps* eu acabei não pesquisando exatamente o porque. Mesmo com essa adição, não impede nada de usar o *Drawable* como era antes.

#### Antes

```
res/
    drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png (48x48 pixels)
    drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png (72x72)
    drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png (96x96)
    drawable-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png (144x144)
    drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png (192x192)
```

#### Hoje

```
res/
    drawable/
    mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png (48x48 pixels)
    mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png (72x72)
    mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png (96x96)
    mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png (144x144)
    mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png (192x192)
```

Mesmo vendo algumas perguntas, ainda não entendi exatamente qual foi o real significado de ter essas alterações. Nas aplicações antigas ainda permanecem *drawable* e aparentemente não sofrem nenhuma alteração e continuam com mesmo propósito.

#### No projeto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Fiz uma breve pesquisa e encontrei algumas respostas, mas não tão satisfatórias assim.

- **[Drawable ou Mipmap?? Qual a diferença?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56882/drawable-ou-mipmap-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a)**
- **[mipmap drawables for icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935810/mipmap-drawables-for-icons)**

Qual a real diferença entre *Mipmap* e *Drawable*? Quando eu devo usar *Mipmap*? Existe alguma limitação caso eu uso *Drawable*?

Comment: Já tive um problema com uma  _png_ com transparência, que ficava na pasta _drawable_,  ela não carregava no celular (no editor aparecia).. Depois de investigar vi que tinha que alterar para a pasta mipmap, só alterei de lugar e funcionou, mas também não sei o porque, assim vai +1 para pergunta..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A diferença entre a pasta ***drawable*** e a ***mipmap*** é que, quando a aplicação é instalada num dispositivo com uma determinada densidade de tela, os *resources* nas pasta referentes às outra densidades são descartados da primeira e mantidos na segunda.

Mas então, pergunta você, por que necessito de manter os *resources* para as outra densidades?

A razão é que alguns dispositivos apresentam os *"launcher icons"* aumentados até cerca de 25%, se existir um *icon* em uma resolução superior ele será usando em vez de ser feita uma ampliação, mantendo assim a qualidade da imagem.

Assim, a pasta ***mipmap*** deve ser usada primariamente para os *"launcher icons"*.

No entanto, a partir do Android 4.2, é possível usar um *mipmap* como *source* de objectos *Bitmap* e, após o Android 4.3, também em objectos *BitmapDrawable*, permitindo manter a qualidade da imagem, por exemplo, durante uma animação que envolva reduções/ampliações.
Tendo as várias imagens na pasta *mipmap* e usando os métodos [setHasMipMap()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setHasMipMap(boolean)) e [hasMipMap()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#hasMipMap()), o Android poderá escolher a que melhor se adequa a cada *frame* da animação.

**Fonte:**

- [How to Support Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support) - *Provide different bitmap drawables for different screen densities.*
- Android 4.3 APIs - [Graphics](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#Graphics) - *Mipmapping for drawables*